# Can't control width and height of video in fancy box

Tags: fancybox

I eventually want to create a photo gallery... clicking on a picture will launch a You Tube video. I am using fancybox 2.0.

I have the video opening up inline but I cannot control its dimensions. Could you please take a look at this page for me and see where I am fouling up.

http://www.bytebrothers.com/bb_tester/Video_lightbox_test.htm

Thank you,
darrell@bytebrothers.com

Comment: you have a javascript error on your page.

Answer (score 2):

This is how your script looks like right now

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.fancyYouTube').fancybox({
   width  : 400,
   height : 300,
   autoSize : false,
   type   : 'swf'
 })
```

and this is how it should look like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.fancyYouTube').fancybox({
   width  : 400,
   height : 300,
   autoSize : false
 });
});
```

you are missing some closing brackets.

On the other hand, if you are using fancybox-media, you don't need to specify `type:'swf'`

**UPDATE**: when targeting youtube videos in `embed` (youtube `iframe` mode) mode, add the class `fancybox.iframe` to your anchor so this

```
<a class="fancyYouTube" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/dx6TZgUSquY">
```

should be this

```
<a class="fancyYouTube fancybox.iframe" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/dx6TZgUSquY">
```

Comment: Thank you JFK for the quick response. For some reason the link to the YT yields "Video not available", yet if I cut and paste it into a browser the video runs fine. Any thoughts? It has, intermittently, worked in the past.

Comment: I didn't notice that you were using youtube's `embed` mode ... please see my edited answer.

Comment: No problem. I appreciate your help very much. It works! Thank you JFK.